# Finding a perpendicular component of a velocity vector relative to a point

Tags: vectors

I have a object which has a position vector(a,b) and velocity vector(l,m). I also have another point(x,y). I want to find the component of the velocity that is perpendicular to the other point.

[image]

I would appreciate any help. Also This is for game development and not some homework.

Comment: You can always decompose a vector $v$ into its components parallel and orthogonal to some other vector (or even subspace) $n$ as $$v = v_\|+v_\bot$$ where $v_\| = \dfrac{v\cdot n}{n\cdot n}n$.  Thus the orthogonal part is simply $$v_\bot = v - \frac{v\cdot n}{n\cdot n}n$$

Comment: for a dumb person, could you please explain what v (seems to be velocity) and n are?

Comment: $v$ and $n$ are any vectors.

Comment: as It turn out this was the correct answer, Thanks. If you perhaps frame it in a answer I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three dimensions you can use the cross product:
$$
\left(\matrix{u_x\\u_y\\u_z}\right) \times \left(\matrix{v_x\\ v_y\\ v_z}\right) =\left(\matrix{ u_y v_z - u_z v_y \\ u_z v_x - u_x v_z\\ u_x v_y - u_y v_x}\right)
$$
for which $||u\times v||= ||u|| ||v|| \sin\left(\angle(u,v)\right)$. (In two dimensions you can just use the last line by pretending to add a $0$ as z component to all vectors.)

With that, you can calculate your 'tangential velocity' as 
$$ 
v_t= \frac{ (a -x)\times v}{||a - x||}
$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm, $||a||=\sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2}$, $a$ is your object with velocity $v$ and $x$ is the other point.

Comment: as I understand doesn't cross product give value which is perpendicular to both the vectors? So won't this value be in z coordinate? The answer is supposed to be in the 2d plane.

Comment: Yes, but technically you can embed the two dimensional plane in three dimensional space. That is what I meant by just putting a $0$ as the third component of the vector. In that case, the cross product has only a z component and everything still works.

Edit: You then have to calculate the direction of $v_t$, which is just $\left(\matrix{ (a-x)_y\\ (a-x)_x}\right)$, perhaps up to a sign.